# Uniqueness of the solution to systems of first-order linear PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, linear-pde, existence-theorems, uniqueness-theorems

**Context:**

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ be an domain.
For functions $A_{jk}^i : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $B_k^i : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ with some regularity, I am interested in the following system of PDEs:
$$
\sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = 1}^m 
A_{jk}^i (x) \frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_j} (x)
+
B_{k}^i (x) f_k (x)
=
0
\ \ \text{for} \ \ 
i = 1, \dots, r
$$
where $f = (f_1, \dots, f_m)$ are variables.
Assume that the number of equations is no less than the number of variables, i.e., $r \geq m.$
Also, assume the Dirichlet boundary condition: $f_k = 0$ on $\partial \Omega.$

**Question:**

It is obvious that $f_k = 0$ is a solution.
I am wondering under what conditions on $A_{jk}^i$ and $B_k^i$ the uniqueness is guaranteed.

**What I have tried:**

I found some potentially useful books/papers/notes.

(1) [Wavefronts and Rays as Characteristics and Asymptotics](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789811226472_0001) by Andrej Bóna and Michael A Slawinski.

In section 1.7 (page 24), they briefly explain how to solve the system. Their setup is almost the same as what I have in mind, but their method relies on the higher-order differentiability of $A_{jk}^i,$ which is not ideal for me.

(2) [Methods of Mathematical Physics Volume II](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/9783527617234) by R. Courant and D. Hilbert.

In section 2.2 (pages 14-15), they address the system saying that by Cramer's rule, one can transform the system into independent PDEs. But I am not pretty sure how I should apply Cramer's rule to differential operators.

(3) [Chapter 2: First Order Equations](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Ekersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/chap2.pdf) by Evy Kersalé from his lecture notes *[Analytic Solutions of Partial Differential Equations (MATH3414)](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Ekersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/outlines.pdf)*.

In section 2.4, he discusses interesting methods to solve the system for $p = 2.$
I would like to know more general treatments.

**What I want:**
I conjecture that a sort of full rankness of $A_{jk}^i$ and $B_k^i$ is sufficient for the uniqueness, but I have not found such a result.
Also, I do not want to put too strong differentiability assumptions on $A_{jk}^i$ and $B_k^i.$
Ideally, they should be up to $C^1.$
Any thoughts and references are helpful.

Thanks!